# Fixed header and footer become displaced at click evnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have trouble with a fixed header and footer in my jquery mobile application. If I click on the screen the fixed header and footer arent fixed anymore they become displaced but I dont know how to fix it. Any opinions to solve that bug?
I' ve created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1513/).

```
    <div style="height:100%; width:100%" class="ui-page" data-role="page" data-position="fixed" id="main">
        <div style="height:10%"" data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
            <a class="ui-btn-left" name="backo" data-icon="back" data-rel="button" ></a>

        <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
        <div style="height:100%; width:100%" data-role="content" id="container">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <div style="width:95%;padding-right:5%;" id="chatOutput">

    </div>
    </ul>
        <div style="height:15%; width:100%;background-color:#e9eaed;border: 0px;border-color: transparent;" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    <div style="width:96%;padding-right:2%;padding-left:2%" class="ui-grid-a">
        <div style="height:100%;width:80%" class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" id="chatText" paceholder="type your text here"></div>
        <div style="height:100%;width:20%" class="ui-block-b"><button style="font-size:90%" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-icon-carat-r" id="chatSend">send</button></div></div>

      </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT: I found this: `$("[data-role=header]").toolbar({ tapToggle: false });` and it works fine.

Comment: try add `position:absolute`

Comment: Wont change sth in better way look: https://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1519/

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-tap-toggle="false"` inside the header and footer divs.

This will prevent the toggle of the header/footer on tap/click

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<div style="height:10%"" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
```

To this:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
```

And, also, change this:

```
<div style="height:15%; width:100%;background-color:#e9eaed;border: 0px;border-color: transparent;" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
```

To this:

```
<div style="background-color:#e9eaed;border: 0px;border-color: transparent;" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1517/)

[Updated jsfiddle with persistent message box](http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1528/)

---

A few sidenotes:

- Inline styling is generally not a good idea; use stylesheets instead.
- Block elements like 'div' do not need width:100%; they will expand to full width by default.
- Validate your html for errors with your built-in browser dev tools, or online tools like validator.w3.org

Comment: Ok thank you that change the displacing in the header but dont the issue with the footer the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1524/

Comment: @Droidboyx I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong with that. What is the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: The footer should be fixed on the bottom. If I click on the middle the footer runs to the button of the document but it should be always at the button of the screen. :)

Comment: Her is a updated demo with a new script: http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1525/ The problem is that when I am at the bottom the header isnt there anymore and if I am at the top the footer isnt at the screen anymore :D  When I dont click anywhere all is right but when I click the problem starts.How can we solve this?

Comment: @Droidboyx I believe the sliding down of the message box is an intended behavior of jquery mobile ui, however, to prevent it from happening, you can remove `data-role="footer"` and add suficient padding (padding-bottom:100px) to your main container to prevent overlapping. Updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1528/

Comment: @ Sage Arslan Ok thank you that solve the problem with the "footer". How can I make the same thing with the header? If I delete `data-role="header"` the bar dont look anymore like a header.

Comment: @Droidboyx If you don't like the header that jquery ui gives you, you'll need to make your own. I've made a basic header for you, you can now style it to your liking. [Check this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1534/)